# The role of the Service Class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I know there's quite a bit out there on this topic, but I couldn't seem to find any that completely answers my questions. I was told to use a Service->DAO->Low level code architecture . I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around is the exact role of the Service class, will one Service class work for a Book DAO and also a user DAO? I was going to have a Service class for each, haveing the Service clas talk to the DAO, take the resulting string and store it in my Book class and User class, then send that object back to the Controller. In my thinking, the Service class is the high level class that delegates all the work to other classes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good questions but probably too broad and subjective for SO.

Comment: A service can be almost anything: a wrapper around a single DAO, a transactional wrapper around operations involving multiple DAOs, a service integrator, blah blah blah. In *your* situation, why not just ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection of service classes, known as a *service tier*, is responsible for carrying out the business logic of an enterprise application. Service classes usually don't map directly to DAOs, since they represent business operations that might involve a large number of domain objects. An example is an order-submission process, where the code responsible for accepting an order has to work with the objects representing orders, customer accounts, financial accounts, and inventory.

Separating the various business operations into different service classes is a design decision that depends on the complexity of the operations, how closely they're related, and so on. Some designers might decide that each business operation should be essentially a separate class (similar to the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)), while others prefer a more comprehensive interface with a richer variety of methods.

The concept of a service tier exists to make sure that all of the business logic is stored in one place and not duplicated. Many modern systems will have several interfaces into the backend, such as a Web application (perhaps with Spring MVC Controllers), a SOAP or REST interface (perhaps with Jersey), and specialized adapters for legacy terminals or other systems. Making these interfaces all adapters around a common service tier ensures that they all behave in a consistent way and that any changes to the service tier are applied to all of the access interfaces.

In your particular case, since you're needing to ask, a single service object will probably be sufficient for your needs. It's always a good idea to list all of the service methods on a separate `interface` and code to that so that you can replace the implementation for testing or future upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Service class may be acting as a layer of abstraction so DAO or data layer is hidden from the "business layer".

The service may talk to multiple DAOs to perform a function in which case it's acting more of a Facade pattern, hiding the complexity of communicating with DAOs to perform the required functionality.

This sort of pattern is seen in the port and adapter or hexagonal architecture in that the business logic is insulated from lower level protocols.

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PortsAndAdaptersArchitecture